# How do I loop through object properties minus the last value pair in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I am trying to loop through objects in node.js javascript. I have the object below:

```
var obj = {
  a: "foo",
  b: "bar",
  c: "foobar",
  d: "something1",
  e: "something2",
  f: "something3"
};
```

I want to loop through all the keys, except the last value pair f:"something3" with javascript.

I tried something like this but did not work

```
 const keys = Object.keys(this.obj)
    for (const key of keys.length-1) {
      console.log(key)
    }
```

I got the following error message `The error just says (keys.length-1) is not iterable`

Comment: That's not how a `for of` works. Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) would likely help as would noting the error thrown by your attempt

Comment: The error just says (keys.length-1) is not iterable

Comment: better off to just skip them in the loop....

Comment: Right because it's not the `keys` array. What you have shown is the same as doing `for(const key of 6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as charlietfl said the reason is that `for(const key of keys.length - 1)` is like writing `for(const key of 5)`, that is not how `for of` loops work.

What I would suggest doing is:

```
var obj = {
    a: "foo",
    b: "bar",
    c: "foobar",
    d: "something1",
    e: "something2",
    f: "something3"
}; 

const keys = Object.keys(obj)
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(obj[keys[i]])
}
```

So what we do here is we do a normal `for (var i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)`

Here our length is `keys.length - 1` which is `5`, so we are going to skip the last one like you want to do.

Then log the obj keys value `console.log(obj[keys[i])`.

Hopefully this is helpful, I have also made a snippet so you can see it in action.

```js
var obj = {
  a: "foo",
  b: "bar",
  c: "foobar",
  d: "something1",
  e: "something2",
  f: "something3"
}; 

const keys = Object.keys(obj)
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
   console.log(obj[keys[i]])
}
```

Comment: @Jin If my answer solved your issue, then feel free to mark it.

Comment: Boren Pedersen, I marked your answer please upvote my post if you can